# Variable change.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying read the article "LIMIT CYCLES FOR A CLASS
OF DISCONTINUOUS GENERALIZED LIENARD POLYNOMIAL DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS" but I can't understand the following:

If I have the system (pag 4, proof pf theorem 1):
$$\dot{r}=- \epsilon(\cos(\theta)F_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) +\sin(\theta)g_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) )\\
\dot{\theta} = -1 +\frac{\epsilon}{r}(\sin(\theta)F_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) - \cos(\theta)g_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) )$$
Take the angle $\theta$ how new independent variable  the differential system become:
$$  \dot{r}=\epsilon(\cos(\theta)F_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) +\sin(\theta)g_{i}(r\cos(\theta)) ) + O(\epsilon^{2}). $$
This my doubt how can i get to the last expresion.
I now how to get the $\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\theta}$ but I don't understand the statement:

> Take the angle $\theta$ how new independent variable.

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer:  Define $\dot{r}:= \frac{\dot{r}}{\dot{\theta}}$ then to find the taylor expansion arround to $\epsilon = 0$. In case ir serve someone later.